# Security Exception while implementing global search for Messaging

Tags: android

I am trying to enable global search for messaging application (i.e., messages can be searched from home screen search box).  I have followed all the steps given in

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html

I am getting the following exception

04-16 12:49:26.917: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(102): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider uri content://mms-sms/search_suggest_query/m?limit=58 from pid=106, uid=10000 requires android.permission.READ_SMS

I have set permission in MmsSmsProvider.java file for read, write sms and global search, but still I get this error.

Can anyone help.

Regards,
Sunil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

in you AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I tried adding the user permission, but still I am getting the same error.